# Confirm old password before changing to new password codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a dashboard with users details which they can edit. I would like to add a password change but before they can change their password how would I validate their current password before letting them change to a new password?

So the form would have 3 fields. First field will have their `current_password`, follow by `new_password` and `confirm_password`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codeigniter comes with a **Form Validation Class** you can find the [documentation here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).
Its purpose is exactly what its name suggest - It will help you validating your form input. Once you get used to it it comes in really handy.

This is how your controller could look:

```
public function change_password() {
   if ($this->input->post()) {
      // user submitted the form
      if (some_encryption_function($this->input->post('current_password'))==password_from_db) { // pseudo code

         $this->load->library('form_validation'); // this should probably belong somewhere else like in the constructor of the controller
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password', 'New Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|matches[confirm_password]');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]');

         if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            data['message'] = validation_errors();
         } else {
            store_new_password_to_db($this->input->post('new_password');
            data['message'] = "Some success message";
         }
         $this->load->view('your_change_password_view',$data);
      }
   }
}
```

This is not a perfect example for the form validation class. Just because you could easily validate those 3 fields without its help. But as its already built in with codeigniter why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

Have them enter their old pass, new password and confirm the new password. Then,

```
if (old pass == password stored in database)
{
    if (new password == confirm password)
     {
          //update password in database
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$oldPass = get_password_from_db();
$currentPass = $this->input->post("old_pass");
$newPass = $this->input->post("new_pass");
$confPass = $this->input->post("conf_pass");
//check if new and confirm pass are same
if(md5($currentPass) == $oldPass) {
    //update query to change to new pass
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is pointing me in the right directions!